# Event Object on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, firefox, object

Sorry, this seems to be a great crowd pleaser... That should be why firefox has not changed their code to be fully compliant with the Event object just like Chrome. I've done my homework, tried several solutions given here on StackOverflow, but nothing seems to work. I have this code:

```
function xpto(e) {
if( !e ) e = window.event;
  var x = e.target||e.srcElement;
alert(x);
    ........
}
```

The call is being made like:

```
<svg id="graph-svg" onclick="xpto(event)" style="outline: none;" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
```

Yes... It's an svg element that I'm trying to get on click. I have not put the complete code because it was not relevant to the question. Bottom line, the

```
alert(x)
```

is always alerting with undefined on Firefox, and working on Chrome like a charm. I can grab the Event on Firefox, but the "x" always cames undefined.

In firefox on the DOM description either Event and SVG are supported. Event is even defined with the "target" and "srcElement" properties for backwards compatibility.

I'm using Firefox 20 on Ubuntu... Can anyone help?

Comment: have you tried console.log(x); in firebug to see more detail?

Comment: Yes, even Firebug it says that "event" on the call is not defined... It show me an error where onclick is supposedly shown like: 

        function onclick(evt) {
xpto(event)
}

I guess it is the definition of onclick on Firefox... Then it falls into the handler...

Comment: When I ran similar code in Firebug... like onclick="doSomething(event)" and in doSomething(event){console.log(event);} it does show up... (and has target by the way)

Comment: Mine has not... It could be because I'm running on Ubuntu, but with your answer I got a hint and exploited it. 

After your reply I went to the code and found out that the argument that works in firefox is not "event" or "Event" but "evt"... The console in Firebug (which should be the real browser name...) showed this:

        function onclick(evt) { xpto(event) }

So with that I realized that the handler was being called with "event" rather than the original argument "evt". Then when it felled into the handler the "event" was passed as "null".

I really, really hope this helps someone.

Comment: The only reason this works in Chrome is that it copied IE's `window.event`, not because it's somehow more "compliant".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a reply from d'alar'cop I went to the code and found out that the argument that works in firefox is not "event" or "Event" but "evt"... The console in Firebug showed this:

```
    function onclick(evt) { xpto(event) }
```

So with that I realized that the handler was being called with "event" rather than the original argument "evt". Then when it felled into the handler the "event" was going "null" ... undefined.

Comment: Yep.  The SVG spec defines that event handlers on SVG elements use `evt` for the argument instead of `event` like HTML does.  Why they decided to not do the same thing as HTML... who knows.  :(

Comment: We are using extensive SVG as well. We recently had to add an event to functions within the SVG. All major browsers were working on multiple OS/devices until we tried Firefox on Android. The error was event is null. Searched the net and found this link within minutes. Your fix undoubtedly saved us hours or days.

Answer (score 4):

Many times I see event handler inlined in HTML code, instead to rely on the more powerful [event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/EventTarget.addEventListener).

Instead to use `onclick` why don't you attach a listener to the `SVG` element? You could try this:

```
var addListener = function (element, event, callback) {
    // We define a cross-browser function
    if (window.addEventListener) {
        // Mozilla/Webkit/Opera
        element.addEventListener(event, callback, false);
    } else {
        // IE
        element.attachEvent('on' + event, callback);
    }
};

// Then we attach the event listener to the SVG element
addListener(document.getElementById('graph-svg'), 'click', function (evt) {
    // Here you can manage the fired event
    alert(evt);
});
```

or, using jQuery:

```
$('#graph-svg').on('click', function(evt){
    alert(evt);
});
```

You can try it with this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ragnarokkr/DtkMX/) (tested with FF 20.0 and Chrome 26 on Ubuntu 12.10).

Of course, inline handlers aren't always evil, but many times they're not the solution, IMHO.

Comment: The problem was not the event handler done in that way... It was the "event" not being detected by my browser. I could do it in any way you told, jquery, raw javascript listener but as soon as I passed "event" it would came up empty on the "target". When I started to pass "evt" it worked. 
My problem was with the browser itself, not the architecture :) But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Yes, FF uses `evt` as global event handler, but my point is that usually using inline code (which in some cases is also forbidden by the enviroment) for event handler is a *bad* habit, because brings to us tons of problems that using the event listener we won't had. You're welcome anyway :)